# Should we nullify global and event listener variables after we used them?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and was learning memory leaks and how to avoid it. I found out that if we use global variables then they are not removed from the memory which can lead to memory leak. Also, variables holding eventListeners are not removed from the memory. The question is should we, as best practice, equalize global variables and variables holding eventListeners to null after we used them and when they are no longer needed for example:

```
var data = 'This is huge data'; 
//After we used data then equalize it to null
data=null;
   var element = document.querySelector('li').addEventListener();
//After we used element then equalize it to null
 element=null;
```

Comment: Don't use global variables, and you shouldn't need to do either of these things

Comment: `addEventListener` does not return anything. I think you did not understand how it works.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, thank you for your kind comments, from your experience should we consider memory leak as a vital thing to take care of, I mean, I read that memory leak is not so important and we can relax since V8 is quite advanced and take care of everything for us.

Comment: @Seblor, from your experience, should we always watch memory leak and do our best to not use global variables?

Comment: @Dickens Of course you should watch out for memory leaks, and of course global variables are bad practice. AFAIK, this applies to (nearly) all programming language.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, if it is nonsense about V8 then please can you give your kind professional recommendation about memory leak(very very briefly) and how you handle memory leak personally(briefly). Please I really need your help

Comment: @Seblor, thank you for your kind comments, is it ok if I always use IIFE and not use global variables at all? If you create a project, will you work with IIFE and not use global variables?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, please I really need your help

Comment: *If you create a project, will you work with IIFE and not use global variables?* This is exactly the right approach. Best to avoid global variables entirely - they're almost never needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any good reason for doing it. Even if there isn't any solid specification for garbage collection in JavaScript (unlike Java), all the modern implementation of the engine provide this mechanism.

For this reason, setting `data = null` won't have any special effect on performances, while `element = null` will just remove the reference but won't affect the listener.

If you want to remove the listener, you have to use `element.removeListener`

Comment: hey Cristian, please Christian since I am newbie to JS, can you give your kind recommendation on how you handle memory heap and how should I habdle it. It is very important for me.

Comment: just very briefly

Comment: please I really need your help

Comment: The answer that you need is "it's not important for you". That's named "micro-optimisation", and it's not a good thing to focus on for a beginner, and (except some edge cases) that's not an argument for advanced engineers as well.

Comment: I have another solution too, it's for some cases like when using .bind() function for handler function, 
you will have just to replace element by the same using .cloneNode() method, example: 
`element.replaceWith(element.cloneNode(true))`  
this trick will replace element by itself and will remove all its listeners to make it a fresh element. But unfortunately, you have to put in consideration that this can affect performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solution to avoid memory leak is to avoid polluting the global variable scope.
You can place your data inside function, the garbage collector will clean the variable after the function is invoked, you can use IIFE for example:

```
(function fnWrapper() {
  var data = 'This is huge data';
  console.log(data);
})();
```

The var data will be deleted from the memory heap after your code runs. (except if it has been used inside nested functions or what they might call "Closure") 
:)